# How do I download a file in python without using the urllib, urllib2 and urllib3 modules? I neither can use request module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem because I need to download a file using python but I cannot use the libraries urllib, urllib2 and urllib3 neither request

If someone can help me I thanks him a lot

Comment: you can use the `wget` package. Why can't you use the other ones?

Comment: I'm doing a job but with this libraries I can do this

Comment: I use python 3.6 and wget doesn't work

Comment: you can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use `subprocess` module and `curl` command

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['curl', 'https://www.google.com'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# do with result
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do wget in terminal to get the package. Why can't you use these!? (I can't ugh comment)

Try using `requests` to get the data of the file and write it a path if you can't use urllib's package.

To download files with `requests` use this example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/how-to-download-large-file-in-python-with-requests-py)

```
def download_file(url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    # NOTE the stream=True parameter
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
                #f.flush() commented by recommendation from J.F.Sebastian
    return local_filename
```

Here's the aiohttp example for async functions:

```
import aiohttp

async def download_file(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
                while True:
                    chunk = await resp.content.read(chunk_size)
                    if not chunk:
                        break
                    fd.write(chunk)

url = "URL"
await download_file(url)
```

I recommend using aiohttp if you don't can't use requests.

Comment: if you can't comment, don't. provide a full answer when you can

Comment: Will do rn, I literally had to transfer devices,

Comment: OP states: "I cannot use the libraries urllib, urllib2 and urllib3 neither request"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, finally I could solve my problem
I give you the solution that I used

```
import * from socket
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((url, port))
    file_mess="GET /" + step2[:5] + " HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
    s.send((file_mess).encode('utf-8'))
    print(s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
    print(s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
```

I used the second print for obtaining all the data, because with the first I only get a 200 OK